# Why is the entanglement of formation upper bounded by the Schmidt number?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, mathematics, quantum-states

I have read many times in several articles (such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05033) that the entanglement of formation EoF puts a lower bound on entanglement dimensionality $d$ (i.e., the Schmidt number):

$$\log_2d\geq E_{\rm{oF}}.$$

However, I was not able to find any proof of this fact. How would one go about proving it?